# Consistir o botao voltar pagina em MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Possuo uma aplicacao web .net mvc de pesquisa de satisfação, onde o usuario preeche todos os dados e clica no botao finalizar. O sistema grava os dados da pesquisa e redireciono ele para outra pagina e envio uma mensagem que finalizacao. Porem os usuarios clicam em voltar, com isso a pagina volta e os dados estao todos ja preenchidos e clicam novamente em finalizar. Porem o sistema esta gravando tudo novamente. Eu poderia consistir ao gravar os dados, mas gostaria de saber se existe alguma funcao para nao permitir ele voltar a pagina, ou.. ao voltar eu conseguir validar se a pesquisa ja foi preenchida.

Comment: Por favor, veja [ask]. Adicione um exemplo mínimo e verificável, da maneira que está não é muito intuitiva.

Answer (score 2):

Você não pode controlar o comportamento de voltar do navegador. Isso é por uma questão de segurança.

O que você pode fazer para resolver o seu problema é o seguinte:

- se os usuários são autenticados no sistema, isso é, possuem nome de usuário e senha (ou logam através de perfis de redes sociais), você pode associar a resposta da pesquisa ao usuário. Assim você garante no máximo um preenchimento da pesquisa por pessoa. Você pode inclusive rejeitar um novo preenchimento se já existir um para o usuário logado;
- se os usuário não são autenticados, gere um token aleatório na sessão do usuário (algo como `Session["tokenPesquisaSatisfacao"] = algumaStringAleatoria`). Ponha o token em um controle do tipo `hidden` na página onde as perguntas são respondidas. Guarde o token junto com a resposta na base de dados. Se o usuário voltar no navegador, ele obterá o mesmo token. Então bastará não permitir a gravação das respostas caso já exista uma pesquisa respondida com o mesmo token.